# Unable to Keystone Screen

Tags: display, xrandr

I am trying to keystone a projector. The projector sits about 5 inches above the table and is pointed down at the table at a 45-degree angle. I have tried xrandr.

Current Code Here

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080 --transform 1.16129,-0.70903,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.00018,1.2
```

The problems I have had include

- Left side of screen being pushed off (can't see unity Status Bar widgets)
- Cant keystone right side of screen (The left side has been fixed if that helps)
- The screen is too tall, because it sits on the table it shines out too far, iI need to compress it not just scale it.
  (I basically need to squish it)

Here are some pictures of my current setup.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't projectors have keystone settings? Setting the keystone for the signal isn't a very good way to do it. You'll either cut stuff out or make the image smaller

Comment: @Zacharee1 It's a small pico AXAA projector and doesn't have a keystone feature built in.